# I keep getting 0 as my output? Why is my programming not running as it should?

Tags: c#

I am calculating a monthly payment and taking in multiple inputs (cash, loan, loan period, interest rate) and then using `GetPayment()` to calculate monthly payment. I am required to use 2 different classes, one being program and the other being `PaymentCalculator()`.

```
namespace ConsoleApp59
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            PaymentCalculator calc1 = new PaymentCalculator();

            calc1.SetCash(GetInput("cash flow: "));

            calc1.SetLoan(GetInput("loan amount: "));

            calc1.SetPeriod(GetInput("loan period (in months): "));

            calc1.SetRate(GetInput("interest rate (ex. 10, 20): "));

            calc1.GetPayment();
            calc1.DisplayPayment();

            ReadKey();
        }
        static double GetInput(string input)
        {
            Write("Please enter " + input);
            double final = double.Parse(ReadLine());
            return final;

        }
    }

    public class PaymentCalculator
    {
        double cash, loan, period, rate, payment;

        public PaymentCalculator()
        {
            cash = 0;
            loan = 0;
            period = 0;
            rate = 0;
            payment = 0;
        }

        public void SetCash(double input)
        {
            cash = input;
        }
        public void SetLoan(double input)
        {
            loan = input;
        }
        public void SetPeriod(double input)
        {
            period = input;
        }
        public void SetRate(double input)
        {
            rate = input;
        }
        public void GetPayment()
        {
            double firstCalculation = (loan * rate / 100);  
            double secondCalculation = (1 - 1 / Math.Pow(1 + rate / 100, period));
            double payment = firstCalculation / secondCalculation;

        }
        public void DisplayPayment()
        {
            WriteLine("\t ----- Payment Calculator -----");
            WriteLine("Monthly Payment: {0:F2}", payment);
        }
    }
}
```

The issue I am running into is when I run the program the output ALWAYS says this:

> Monthly Payment: 0:00

It shouldn't be saying that, but instead any *other* number than `0.00`. I have no clue why this is happening because I can't find any error in my code.

Please somebody tell me why this is happening and what can I do to fix it so I can get actual numbers as my answers.

Comment: Try to debug your program :) see for example https://csharp.net-tutorials.com/debugging/introduction/

Comment: A method called **Get**Payment should return a value.  Perhaps a better name for this method is `CalculatePayment`.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is in your GetPayment method.

```
public void GetPayment()
{
    double firstCalculation = (loan * rate / 100);  
    double secondCalculation = (1 - 1 / Math.Pow(1 + rate / 100, period));
    double payment = firstCalculation / secondCalculation; // <-- right here.
}
```

You are declaring a new local variable named payment, which shadows the class field that is used in your `DisplayPayment` method. Since it's never updated, the class field remains the initialized value of 0, which is what's ultimately displayed.

Instead, assign the calculated value to the class field.

```
payment = firstCalculation / secondCalculation;
```